# How to remove the time delay before a QToolTip is displayed?

Tags: qt, tooltip

I have a custom `QGraphicsItem` with a `QToolTip`. When hovering with the mouse on them the tool tip shows fine, but there is a small delay before the tool tip shows.

How can I decrease that delay, so the tool tip will show immediately?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the documentation for [`QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent*)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) you can read the following description:

> If you want to show a tooltip immediately, while the mouse is moving
>   (e.g., to get the mouse coordinates with `QMouseEvent::pos()` and show
>   them as a tooltip), you must first enable mouse tracking as described
>   above. Then, to ensure that the tooltip is updated immediately, you
>   must call `QToolTip::showText()` instead of `setToolTip()` in your
>   implementation of `mouseMoveEvent()`.

But instead of using the `mouseMoveEvent`, you could also use the [`QWidget::enterEvent(QEvent*)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#enterEvent).

Comment: I used the first option you gave, it's worked great, thanks a lots.

Comment: If an event filter is already installed on the target object, QEvent::HoverMove type would suit this scenario best. Unlike QEvent::MouseMove, there is no need to enable mouse tracking on the object for it to work. I also noticed that using this event introduces much less annoying tooltip drawing stutter (I don't know where it comes from).

Comment: How about the other way around, delaying a tooltip to be distractive right away?