# PySide: Instant tooltips (no delay before showing the tooltip)

Tags: python, tooltip, pyside, qtreeview

The tool I'm building uses tooltips to display extra info about a file before you click on it.  It would be great if someone could lend some insight into how to accomplish this.  I'm about a month into PySide so I'm having trouble deciphering these advanced examples/answers I've found online, so a simple code example with some comments will help me out a lot.

Here's what I have so far. I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to events, so this is the best I could do with the code examples I have:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from shiboken import wrapInstance
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui

def get_parent():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return wrapInstance( long( ptr ), QtGui.QWidget )   

############################################        
''' Classes '''
############################################
class Main_Window( QtGui.QDialog ):
    def __init__( self, parent=get_parent() ):
        super( Main_Window, self ).__init__( parent )

        self.setMouseTracking(True)                                      # Set tracking

        self.create_gui()
        self.create_layout()
        self.create_connections()
        self.get_contents()
        self.shapeItems = []


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------  # Mouse things
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton):
            self.moveItemTo(event.pos())  

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------  # Mouse things
    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.ToolTip:
            helpEvent = event
            index = self.itemAt(helpEvent.pos())
            if index != -1:
                QtGui.QToolTip.showText(helpEvent.globalPos(), self.shapeItems[index].toolTip())
            else:
                QtGui.QToolTip.hideText()
                event.ignore()

            return True

        return super(Main_Window, self).event(event)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_gui( self ):
        self.tv_model=MyModel()
        self.tv_file_list = File_List( self )

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_layout( self ):
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout( self )
        self.main_layout.addWidget( self.tv_file_list )
        self.setLayout( self.main_layout )

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_contents(self):
        self.tv_model.clear()
        self.tv_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["name","date"])
        contents=["path1","path2"]
        for path in contents:
            date = self.get_date(path)
            self.add_file(path,date)
        self.tv_file_list.setColumnWidth(0, 150)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_file(self, name, date):
        name = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
        name.setToolTip(name.text())
        name.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_DirOpenIcon))
        date = QtGui.QStandardItem(date)
        self.tv_model.appendRow([name, date])

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_date(self, path):
        return "a date"

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_connections( self ):
        self.tv_file_list.clicked.connect( self.on_click )

    # slots --------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_click(self, item ):
        index = self.tv_file_list.selectedIndexes()[0]
        item = self.tv_model.itemFromIndex(index).text()
        print item

############################################
class MyModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def flags(self, index):
        flag = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.isValid():
            flag |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable 
        return flag

############################################
class File_List( QtGui.QTreeView ):
    ''' Create the file filters '''
    def __init__( self, mainUIWindow, parent=get_parent() ):
        super( File_List, self ).__init__( parent )

        self.setModel(mainUIWindow.tv_model)
        self.setIndentation(0)
        self.setColumnWidth(0,500)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.setStyleSheet("QToolTip { color: rgb(170,170,170); background-color: rgb(20,20,20); border: 1px rgb(20,20,20); }")


############################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # workaround for a bug in maya
    try:
        tree_view_ui.close()
        tree_view_ui.deleteLater()
    except:
        pass

    tree_view_ui = Main_Window()
    tree_view_ui.show()

    try:
        tree_view_ui.show()
    except:
        tree_view_ui.close()
        tree_view_ui.deleteLater()
```

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720465/how-to-change-the-time-delay-before-a-qtooltip-shows) is a post describing how to create instant tooltips, but without any code examples I'm at a loss for how to write this.  The documentation wasn't really much of a help either (it really should have simple examples for beginners).

[HERE](https://github.com/PySide/Examples/blob/master/examples/widgets/tooltips/tooltips.py) is a code that shows how to implement mouse move events, but I haven't been able to get it to work in my own example above.  I keep getting errors that say: "TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type" and "AttributeError: 'Main_Window' object has no attribute 'itemAt'"

Again, any help or thoughts would be great.  Thank you

**SOLUTION**

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from shiboken import wrapInstance
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui

def get_parent():
    ptr = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return wrapInstance( long( ptr ), QtGui.QWidget )   

############################################        
''' Classes '''
############################################
class Main_Window( QtGui.QDialog ):
    def __init__( self, parent=get_parent() ):
        super( Main_Window, self ).__init__( parent )

        self.create_gui()
        self.create_layout()
        self.create_connections()
        self.get_contents()

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_gui( self ):
        self.tv_model=MyModel()
        self.tv_file_list = File_List( self )
        self.tv_file_list.setMouseTracking(True)                 # Set mouse tracking

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_layout( self ):
        self.main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout( self )
        self.main_layout.addWidget( self.tv_file_list )
        self.setLayout( self.main_layout )

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_contents(self):
        self.tv_model.clear()
        self.tv_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["name","date"])
        contents=["path1","path2"]
        for path in contents:
            date = self.get_date(path)
            self.add_file(path,date)
        self.tv_file_list.setColumnWidth(0, 150)

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def add_file(self, name, date):
        name = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
        user = "me"
        name.setToolTip("<b>{0}</b><br><b>{1}</b>".format(name.text(), user) ) # Here's where I set the tooltip
        name.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QtGui.QStyle.SP_DirOpenIcon))
        date = QtGui.QStandardItem(date)
        self.tv_model.appendRow([name, date])


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def get_date(self, path):
        return "a date"


    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def create_connections( self ):
        self.tv_file_list.clicked.connect( self.on_click )
        self.tv_file_list.entered.connect( self.handleItemEntered )  # New connection

    # slots --------------------------------------------------------------
    def on_click(self, item ):
        index = self.tv_file_list.selectedIndexes()[0]
        item = self.tv_model.itemFromIndex(index).text()
        print item

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------
    def handleItemEntered(self, index):                                        # New slot
        if index.isValid():
            QtGui.QToolTip.showText(
                QtGui.QCursor.pos(),
                index.data(),
                self.tv_file_list.viewport(),
                self.tv_file_list.visualRect(index)
                )


############################################
class MyModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def flags(self, index):
        flag = QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled
        if index.isValid():
            flag |= QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable 
        return flag

############################################
class File_List( QtGui.QTreeView ):
    ''' Create the file filters '''
    def __init__( self, mainUIWindow, parent=get_parent() ):
        super( File_List, self ).__init__( parent )

        self.setModel(mainUIWindow.tv_model)
        self.setIndentation(0)
        self.setColumnWidth(0,500)
        self.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.NoFocus)
        self.setStyleSheet("QToolTip { color: rgb(170,170,170); background-color: rgb(20,20,20); border: 1px rgb(20,20,20); }")


############################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # workaround for a bug in maya
    try:
        tree_view_ui.close()
        tree_view_ui.deleteLater()
    except:
        pass

    tree_view_ui = Main_Window()
    tree_view_ui.show()

    try:
        tree_view_ui.show()
    except:
        tree_view_ui.close()
        tree_view_ui.deleteLater()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is much easier to do using the treeview's [entered](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#entered) signal. And if you use the overload of [showText](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtooltip.html#showText) that takes a `rect` argument, `QToolTip` will automatically do the rest.

Here's a simple demo:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.view = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
        self.view.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.view.entered.connect(self.handleItemEntered)
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        for text in 'One Two Three Four Five'.split():
            model.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(text))
        self.view.setModel(model)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

    def handleItemEntered(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            QtGui.QToolTip.showText(
                QtGui.QCursor.pos(),
                index.data(),
                self.view.viewport(),
                self.view.visualRect(index)
                )

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 200, 200)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you!  This works great for accessing the item's name, but I'd like to be able to access additional data that I store under each item when I add it to the view (in my main code I'm storing the user who created the file as well as an image of the file).  Any thoughts on how to accomplish this?  I'm thinking that I have to replace handleItemEntered's index.data() with the argument I'm using for setToolTip().  Is there a simpler way?  I've added a solution section to show my current code and explain what I'm talking about in this comment.

Comment: @MikeBourbeau. You should not set the tooltip on the item anymore. It should be constructed within the `handleItemEntered` slot and passed to `showText`. The item can be retrieved with `self.view.model().itemFromIndex(index)`. If you need to add extra data to the item, use [setData](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditem.html#setData) with a custom role.